# Symfony2: ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for FOS\UserBundle\Model\User::hasRole()

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to create a function that would allow me to delete users created thanks to FOS. But every time I'm getting this error:

> ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   FOS\UserBundle\Model\User::hasRole(), called in
>   /home/symfony_test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php
>   on line 366 and defined in
>   /home/symfony_test/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Model/User.php
>   line 300

I can't figure out how to get rid of this problem.

My function:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, User $user = null)
{
    if (!$user) {
        $this->session->getFlashBag()->set(
            'warning',
            $this->translator->trans('users.messages.user_not_found')
        );
        return new RedirectResponse(
            $this->router->generate('user')
        );
    }

    $userForm = $this->formFactory->create(
        new UserType(),
        $user,
        array(
            'validation_groups' => 'user-delete'
        )
    );

    $userForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($userForm->isValid()) {
        $user = $userForm->getData();
        $this->userModel->delete($user);
        $this->session->getFlashBag()->set(
            'success',
            $this->translator->trans('users.messages.success.delete')
        );
        return new RedirectResponse(
            $this->router->generate('user')
        );
    }

    return $this->templating->renderResponse(
        'AppBundle:User:delete.html.twig',
        array('user'=>$user,
            'form' => $userForm->createView())
    );

}
```

Comment: This error can happen when you have a field named `role` in your form and the property accesor try access to this property through `hasRole()`, `getRole()`, `isRole()`, etc. If you have a form named `UserType` you have probably a field named `role` instead of `roles`. Check this maybe a typo.

Comment: Full stacktrace would be helpful.